# Is it possible to build native gdb for Linux-ARM on Linux-x86-64?

Tags: linux, gdb, arm, cross-compiling, ncurses

I'm trying to build a native ARM GDB for an ARM board to use. Since it lacks a lot of the tools GDB needs for compilation, I'm trying to build it on my x86 machine.

```
./configure --host=arm-linux-gnueabi --target=arm-linux-gnueabi && make
```

However, half way through the build process, it complains that "termcap library" is missing. I think it means it couldn't find an ARM version of the library for it to use. So, is there a possible workaround, or should I not bother with this approach and think of another way?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this for your "ARM board".  You need to compile GDB library dependencies (e.g. the termcap library) and install them where the cross compiler can find them before you can build GDB.  Without a more specific description about the cross compilation toolchain and board it's hard to give more specific advice that will be helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

I cross build GDB for several Linux targets for my ELLCC cross development tool project (http://ellcc.org). You do need a few libraries built for the target to do a build. In addition  to the standard C library, I used libedit, zlib, expat, and ncurses.